# How to implement one method with different parameters. C#

Tags: c#

guys, please tell me how this logic can be pulled into a separate method, since there is a duplication of code, but slightly different by the comparison operator. C#.

```
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
        {
            if (r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom)
                return 0;
            if (r1.Left <= r2.Left && r1.Right >= r2.Right && r1.Top <= r2.Top && r1.Bottom >= r2.Bottom)
                return 1;
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: The logic is fine - leave it as is.

Comment: Why would you want to split it? It's fine as it is. There is no "duplication of code" since you are doing different comparisons which lead to different results ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract a somewhat simpler method

```
public static bool IsLeftRectangleCompletelyWithinRightRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    return (r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom)
}
```

and then use it like

```
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    if (IsLeftRectangleCompletelyWithinRightRectangle(r1, r2))
        return 0;
    if (IsLeftRectangleCompletelyWithinRightRectangle(r2, r1))
        return 1;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Haha. One of the downsides of the mobile site is there are no "an answer has been posted" notifications.. but clearly wither great minds think alike or fools seldom differ :)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could have

```
    public static bool IsR1InsideR2(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom);
    }
```

And then call it twice, swapping the rects over for the second call:

```
var a = ...
var b = ...

if(IsR1InsindeR2(a,b))
  return 0; //or whatever you did with the 0
if(IsR1InsindeR2(b,a))
  return 1; //or whatever
return -1; //or whatever
```

Making it an extension or instance method might improve readability:

```
    public static bool Inside(this Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        return r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom);
    }

    //usage
    a.Inside(b);
```

Also if these are `System.Drawing.Rectangle`s check out their Contains method..